# Collapsed Navbar no longer appears, what happened?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was using the carousel template page and it comes with code for a NavBar that collapses when the screen width is less than a certain px size. And I was using brackets with the live preview and the navbar would collapse properly.

I made changes to the carousel and font sizes in the nav bar. Now when the screen width is small, the nav bar doesn't show the individual list items (as expected) but the button for the collapsed nav doesn't appear.

I am using chrome to view it.

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

Edit: I figured out what happened.

I changed the following from auto to a fixed width of 1000px. This caused my dropdown button to show up way off the page when it was a small width.

```
.navbar-wrapper .navbar .container {
  width: auto;
}
```

In order to fix this, I added the above code (but set to 1000px) in the media query section of the CSS so that it only applies to larger width screens.

Comment: Can you please provide the changes you've made and code?

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle example.

Comment: I figured it out, see my edit. I override the CSS for the larger screen sizes without realizing it would move my dropdown button over really far off the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what happened.

I changed the following from auto to a fixed width of 1000px. This caused my dropdown button to show up way off the page when it was a small width.

```
.navbar-wrapper .navbar .container {
  width: auto;
}
```

In order to fix this, I added the above code (but set to 1000px) in the media query section of the CSS so that it only applies to larger width screens.